# Запуск *Cmd процесса с низкими привилегиями

Tags: windows, golang, cmd, docker, permissions

Нужно запустить программу так чтоб она не могла создавать папки/создавать интернет соединение и не делать ничего лишнего
От программы нужно получить только выходные данные которые она напишет в командную строку
Нужно исключить вариант запуск таких программ которые могут "навредить" компу который её исполняет
P.S. Делаю программу которая тестирует другие программы которые получают данные на входе и выводят результат.
Хорошим вариантом был бы запуск в docker контейнере, но Docker слишком требовательный для ПК которые стоят в учебных заведениях. Но если Docker то пожалуйста какое нибудь "изящное" решение.
Предпологается использование в учебных заведениях на машинах под **Windows 10**
**Заранее Спасибо!** как минимум если вы пытались подумать над этим:D
Пример кода ([источник](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#example_Cmd_StdinPipe)):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("cmd", "/c", "program.exe")
    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    go func() {
        defer stdin.Close()
        io.WriteString(stdin, "something")
    }()

    out, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", out)
}
```

Comment: В среднем случае, нужно просто запускать этот процесс от имени пользователя (и группы), у которого нет никаких привилегий. Как там это всё устроено в Windows 10, я толком, к сожалению, не знаю. Вот пример, как подменить `uid`, `gid` для `exec.Cmd`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21706757/1816872